# Menu Breaks in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm having an issue that only appears when using Chrome.

I have a menu at the top, a search bar, and then another bottom navigation menu below that.

[image 1: menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJpwM.png)

On Chrome, when I highlight over the top menu, the menu items appear like this (behind the bottom navigation):

[image 2: menu breaking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8BtW.png)

And I can't select the items that are directly on top of or below the bottom nav menu. I can hover over menudrop1 and menudrop2 but I can't select menudrop3 (from image 2)

In Firefox and other browsers, this doesn't happen. And in addition, in Chrome the drop down appears completely opaque, whereas in Chrome, it has a much lower opacity.

The weird thing is, this doesn't happen everywhere on the site.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post some code so that we can help?

Comment: Hi, could you clarify this? , in Chrome the drop down appears completely opaque, whereas in Chrome, it has a much lower opacity.

Answer (score 0):

Use `z-index: 1;` for your submenu ( parent of `menudrop1, menudrop2 and ...` )

`Another menu | item1 and ...` probably causing this problem